# How to use select() transformation in Apache Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am following the Intro to Spark course on edX. However, I cant understand few things, following is an lab assignment. FYI, I am not looking for solution.

I am not able to understand as why I am receiving the error

> TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable

Following is the code

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import regexp_replace, trim, col, lower
def removePunctuation(column):
    """

    Args:
        column (Column): A Column containing a sentence.

    """

    # This following is giving error. I believe I am calling all the rows from the dataframe 'column' where the attribute is named as 'sentence'
    result = column.select('sentence') 

    return result

sentenceDF = sqlContext.createDataFrame([('Hi, you!',),
                                         (' No under_score!',),
                                         (' *      Remove punctuation then spaces  * ',)], ['sentence'])
sentenceDF.show(truncate=False)
(sentenceDF
 .select(removePunctuation(col('sentence')))
 .show(truncate=False))
```

Can you be little elaborate? TIA.

Comment: Reason for down voting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The column parameter is not a DataFrame object and, therefore, does not have access to the select method. You'll need to use other functions to solve this problem.

Hint: Look at the import statement.